# Fedora 5.5 kernel seems to be causing issues with RTL8822BE wifi adapter

Tags: fedora, kernel, wifi, drivers, realtek

A recent upgrade from the 5.4 to 5.5 kernel has resulted in me not being able to use wifi on my laptop. At the login screen, I see the connection is established. After logging in, the system hangs for 2 or 3 seconds, and then I get a bunch of warnings and cannot see any WiFi networks, despite the adapter apparently being active.

The output from `lspci -k` is as follows

```
$ lspci -k
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter (rev ff)
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_pci
    Kernel modules: rtwpci
```

I can connect to the internet using an usb ethernet adapter.

`dmesg` output is [here](https://pastebin.com/DCkLAfCs).

Also, I get intermittent hangs since this issue began (everything freezes for +- 1 second). I imagine this is caused by a spurt of interrupts from a buggy driver, but I don't know.

Booting with the 5.4.21 kernel appears to fix the problem, here's `lspci` on 5.4.21

```
$ lspci -k
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device b023
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_pci
    Kernel modules: rtwpci
```

Answer (score 1):

You should head over to http://bugzilla.redhat.com and report the issue. After booting with an older kernel and checking the card/setup works, and trying the latest kernel (I've seen several kernel updates since 5.5 got shipped).